# Why do we need refresh tokens in JWT

Tags: authentication, jwt, authorization

I'm just learning JWT in nodejs, and I found out about refresh tokens.

As far as I understand, a user gets an access token and a refresh token. After the access token expires, a request containing the refresh token is made to get a new access token. To get a new access token, the server checks if the received refresh token is contained in a database. If the refresh token is stolen, it can easily be deleted from the DB and prevent further refreshes.

My question is: Why don't we just make the access tokens behave like refresh tokens? i.e. We store them in a database and check if they are there when making a request, and when compromised we just delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key element to answering your question is: You need to add an expiration date on access tokens you deliver to clients. This is the main purpose with refresh token.

Imagine someone steels your access_token, and you didn't make it expirable: It means that as long as you didn't discover that your access_token has been stolen, you're giving literaly a lifetime free pass to whoever has it.

With refresh tokens and expirable access_tokens, you know that the window of vulnerability is really small.

Now your second question: Why don't we make access_tokens behave like refresh_tokens ?

The key idea here is to keep your refresh_token in a safe spot, and only expose access_tokens.

And by the way, refresh_tokens have one job: Carry information to generate new access_tokens, access_tokens on the other hand have their own job: Carry information necessary to give you direct access to resources.

If you pay attention to most serious websites, they have a centralized auth server that serves access_tokens.

Answering comments:

**Key difference between them is: refresh token key is like a master key, it stays on the authorization server and is never ever shared with any other server, unlike access token key, it can be passed to another server to authenticate users**

in other words:

- auth.yourapp.com: stores **access_token_key and refresh_token_key**
- api.yourapp.com: stores **access_token_key ONLY**, to make sure that users did actualy authenticate on your auth.yourapp.com domain, and api.yourapp.com can easily confirm that. if access_token_key has been compromised, vulnerability has a shorter lifetime, and you can easily isolate the attacked server.

**if one of your servers is compromised, the rest is safer.**

Comment: I understand the idea of making access tokens expirable. But I still don't understand, how are refresh tokens saved more securely then access tokens? They are both sent to the client side, only difference is access tokens are sent with every request and refresh tokens are sent once every 15 minutes or so. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edited my answer: Access tokens get an expiration date, and refresh tokens are revokable in case they've been stolen. it's a necessary extra layer of protection for your users.